# How to apply alpha blending on image using another image DirectX 9?

Tags: c++, image, shader, directx, directx-9

I want to get such effetct in Direct3D 9

[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xn5a.png)

Please, give me an example of code how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't exactly what you want, but might be enough to get you started. It shows different types of blend effects using Direct2D, which you can use in a D3D app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/blend

No idea if this is compatible with D3D9 though.

Comment: Migrate to D3D11 and use Direct2D, or keep Direct3D9 and write a pixel shader: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-writing-shaders-9 something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726008/directx9-additive-blending-with-alpha